Some hard objects!
Figure out what the following diagram represents and complete it by placing objects and numbers in number 3 and 4. Number 3 might be a bit ambiguous, but as long as you got the correct idea, it's fine.


As an aside: the most nearly equilateral triangular arrangement of three objects in the #2 and #5 grids would have the bottom left element moved one place up and the top element moved one place to the right.

The complete diagram looks like this:

 

The hard objects in the title ...

 ... are the Platonic solids. They are ordered by the number of the faces, starting at the top::

 1 The tetrahedron has 4 triangles.
 2 The cube has 6 squares.
 3 The octahedron has 8 triangles.
 4 The dodecahedron has 12 pentagons.
 5 The icosahedron has 20 triangles.

 The symbols in each grid are the shape of a face and the number is the number of faces.

 The number and arrangement of those symbols correspond to the number of edges, that is the shape of each face in the next solid in the series as indicated by the arrows. So for the tetrahedron, there are four triangles arranged in a square, because this solid has triangles as faces, but the next solid, the cube, has squares.

 Number 3, the octahedron, is hard to draw, because the next solid, the dodecahedron, is made up of pentagons. These are hard to arrange in a 5×5 grid. One can chose to put the 2nd and 4th vertices in the second or third row, but either way, it looks off. (I've chosen the second row.)


lbh jnag cragn-, abg urcgn-

Bah, that's all Greek to me! Fixed.

Well done! And yes 3 wasn't as clear as the others but anyways, your reasoning is correct, everything good!
